# Postman does not show image files when trying to browse for image files

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I wanted to upload images file through postman but when I browser for files it does not show images files , I am using ubuntu by the way.

[image]

when i click select files , its empty

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn the interceptor off

[image]